# Why do we need to spawn another process when invoking the public Main can be made possible?

Tags: c#

Suppose that I have 3 separate .net core console application projects: `HelloWorld`, `Consumer`, and `Spawner`.

Assume the assembly `HelloWorld` comes from a third party. And I know its `Main` method is public.

**HelloWorld:**

```
namespace HelloWorld
{
    public class HelloWorld
    {
        public static void  Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        }
    }
}
```

**Consumer:**

```
namespace Consumer
{
    class Consumer
    {
        static void  Main()
        {
            HelloWorld.HelloWorld.Main();
        }
    }
}
```

**Spawner:**

```
namespace Spawner
{
    class Spawner
    {
        static void  Main()
        {
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "HelloWorld.exe";
            p.Start();
            p.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
}
```

## Questions

Now I want to make use of the `HelloWorld` assembly. 
Which method I have to implement, invoking as I did in the `Consumer` project or spawning as in `Spawner`  project?

What are the differences between invoking the `public Main`  of an assembly and invoking the assembly with `Process`?

I am thinking of why we don't always make the `Main` public so others can invoke it with 2 options: calling the method or spawning a new process. Or my understanding is wrong? Any comments are also welcome!

Comment: obviously with second you are creating another process ... first is just a method call from another assembly

Comment: That and the call stack looks a little different because your calling code is on it.

Comment: [What's the difference between an Application, Process, and Services?](https://superuser.com/questions/209654/whats-the-difference-between-an-application-process-and-services) with first code you have only Consumer process with second you have Spawner and HelloWorld processes

Comment: @Selvin: How to choose between these two options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are the differences between invoking the public Main of an assembly and invoking the assembly with Process?

`Consumer.Main` calls `HelloWorld.Main` just as if it were any other method, so `HelloWorld.Main` runs in the **same** process (and thread, etc.) as `Consumer`. You can pass strongly-typed arguments to it, `HelloWorld` and `Consumer` will share `static` state, if one part causes a crash both parts will stop, etc.

`Spawner.Main` starts a **separate** process; see [the documentation for `Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=netframework-4.8). It's just as if you had invoked `HelloWorld` on the command line yourself. There's no shared state between `Spawner` and `HelloWorld`. The process `Spawner` starts doesn't even need to be written in C# or for .NET.

Typically:

- If `HelloWorld` is a library, then the person who wrote `HelloWorld` expects you to reference it and call it from your own code. But a name like `Main` is very rare in this scenario; normally there are many methods you can call to do different things, which have more specific names, parameters, return types, etc.
- If `HelloWorld` is as a stand-alone app, then the person who wrote `HelloWorld` expects you to call it as a separate process, including from technology stacks that might not be the same as the caller. (E.g., C# can use the `Process` object to start processes for programs that were written in many other languages.)

> I am thinking of why we don't always make the Main public to allow others to invoke the assembly with 2 options: calling the method or spawning a new process.

You don't always *want* to give people the choice. Maybe your `Main` does some essential setup that the rest of your program needs - in that case, you don't want someone else to call your `Main` as part of some separate program, which might be set up differently.

Comment: OK. Thank  you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You pretty much answered yourself, **you don't** need to spawn a separate process. You can call the public `Main()` from a different console application and it will work.

However, if you encounter such situation, you probably have to question yourself why are these separate in the first place. Different entry points are necessary to keep these things running independently of each other, to be deployed separately, etc. The obvious biggest difference is that when spawning a different process, it automatically runs completely in parallel.

Comment: Assume the assembly `HelloWorld` comes from a third party. And I know its `Main` method is public.  As a client (aka consumer), which method I have to implement when I want to invoke the assembly? Just invoking as I did in the `Consumer` project or spawning as in `Spawner`  project?

Comment: I don't think that's a common or practice, or desired anyway. You don't want to share stack with a third party assembly that was designed to run standalone (.exe). A third party assembly library (.dll) such as an SDK, would normally present public classes and specific methods you can invoke. If you have no alternative, spawning seems to me to be the reasonable way. Note that the executable does not even need to be .NET in that case.